# Upload error to App Store.No Architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm encountering this error when I upload archive file to App Store from xcode.
[image]

My environment are
UNITY 2017
xcode10

I could upload before.But after I implemented Unity-iOS bridge.
This error occurred.
I referred about Unity-iOS bridge.
https://medium.com/@kevinhuyskens/implementing-swift-in-unity-53e0b668f895

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I still need help....